# SQL Server - "notrans" option in Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a question about something that already solved, but I do not understand the solution, can someone explaind?

This is the scenario:

I have Liked Server between server x and y.

The Link Server created on server x to do read/write operations on server y.

I can update a table on server y thru session of SQL on server x, but
when i do update thru an application i get this error:

**The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "somename" was unable to begin a distributed transaction**

I asked a senior consultant that suggest to write **notrans:** before
the update statment, like this:

**notrans:update  statment**

It is work, can anyone explain why? I did not found anything over the net.

Comment: Does it also work if you write `THIS_IS_A_LABEL_FOR_GOTO_STATEMENTS_AND_NOT_AN_OPTION:UPDATE`?

Comment: No, this is like the "notrans" option? what is the "notrans" option?

Comment: My point is: there is no such option, and that syntax is legal only because "notrans" is interpreted as a label. If you can consistently show that you never get that error when your write `NOTRANS:`, and always get that error when you write `NOT_NOTRANS:`, then you're on to something. Otherwise, I call coincidence.